# What basics can one learn from an SQL DUMP about Databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently took an SQL dump of a POSTGRES database off a small production app and opened it up on Sublime. The SQL dump has very neatly structured lines like so:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;
```

and so on. What can I learn about POSTGRES or databases in general by reading through this SQL file? I'm largely new to databases and want to learn how they (POSTGRES) work.

Comment: Don't start with a db dump, start with the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dump has absolutely nothing to tell you about database engines work. In this case, it is a representation of the internal state (tables, view, references, rows of data, and so on...) in a human-readable language (SQL). In other cases it can be a binary file (that will contain more or less the same information).

If you want to learn how to "operate" a relational database, start from the manual, learn SQL. If you want to learn how a relational database engine works start from the code. Both PostgreSQL and SQLite, two very different, great database engines are open source: just go dig the code.